# CSS Grid Template Columns: Height is not set for item

Tags: css, css-grid

I have the following CSS Grid container:

```
.project-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(215px, 518px));
  gap: 15px 15px;
}
```

I thought that with `minmax(215px, 518px)` it will set an item of `215px height` and `518px height`.

But what happens is that 518px is set to width but the height is 160px and not 215px.

What do I have to set, to have a fixed height for each item?
When I set `grid-template-rows: 215px;` only the first row is effected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought that with `minmax(215px, 518px)` it will set an item of `215px height` and `518px height`.

These are the values of `grid-template-columns`, so you're setting widths, not heights.

---

> What do I have to set, to have a fixed height for each item? When I set `grid-template-rows: 215px;` only the first row is effected.

Use `grid-auto-rows: 215px`. This sets the height of all undefined rows to 215px height.

Comment: So `minmax(auto, 518px)` would be better for the columns?

Comment: If you want each column to have a minimum width set by the content length, and a maximum width of 518px, then yes.